# multiplicative persistence in python

Tags: python

I need help with my code. It is supposed to multiply the digits in a number that I provide as an input. This doesn't work because every time I run the program this is all I get:

```
multiplicative persistence result:  0
multiplicative persistence result:  0
multiplicative persistence result:  0
multiplicative persistence result:  0
```

this just keeps on looping.

```
second = str(raw_input("what number do you want to apply the multiplicative persistence to? "))
while len(second)>1:
    ans=0
    for num in second:
        ans=ans * int(num)
    b=str(ans)
    print "multiplicative persistence result: ",b
raw_input()
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing multiplication with addition. The multiplicative identity is 1, not 0.

Answer (score 1):

I have one simple working

```
def per(n,steps=0):
    if len (str(n))==1:
        print(n)
        print "TOTAL STEPS" + str(steps)
        return "DONE"
steps += 1
digits = [int(i)for i in str(n)]
result = 1
for j in digits:
    result *= j
print(result)
per(result,steps)
```

> > > per(277777788888899)

This one is a basic manually edited input function. The function is only there to be a sort of input since the code itself is 'unneeding' of a more complex and ready-to-use method due to the fact it is live editing as shown in the video. The actual calculation process happens in

```
steps += 1
digits = [int(i)for i in str(n)]
result = 1
for j in digits:
    result *= j
```

Don't rely on the first part of the code since the actual process is in the second part.

Credit to Numberphile
video =====https://youtu.be/Wim9WJeDTHQ
channel ===== Numberphile (in youtube)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple program to calculate the persistence of a number:

```
number = int(input("enter number"))
product = 1
persistence = 0
print(number)
while number > 9:
    for digit in range(0, len(str(number))):
        product *= int(str(number)[digit])
    print(product)
    persistence += 1
    number = product
    product = 1
print("persistence:", persistence)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not reducing `len(second)` so of course it never exits

```
def solve_to_1(second):
    answ = 1
    for num in second:
        answ *= int(num)
    print "Intermediate:",answ
    if answ >= 10: #still to big recursively call it
        return solve_to_1(str(answ))
    return answ

result = solve_to_1("1234123")
print "FINAL:",result
```

Comment: i should have included this, but it has to keep on looping until the final result has one digit.

Comment: if any digit is zero you do realize that the answer will be zero?

Answer (score 0):

```
second = input("what number do you want to apply the multiplicative persistence to? ")

result = 1
for digit in second:
    result *= int(digit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is always returning true, therefore the loop keeps on going.
Rather just iterate through the string you're unpacking.

```
for num in second:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop that you have set up is infinite. In order to use a while loop, you need to modify the condition that it uses, in this case `len(second)`.